# How do I sync the GameObjects to server in C# unity?

Tags: unity, c#, networking

I have been working on Game that consists of 10 Game Objects that have to be sync by the server values. The server decides that which game object will win and then sends command to my side(Client side) but I am not able to match the server values to mine then what can I do to sort out this problem?
The track is kind of horse racing track i.e. straight and then circular.
Any help would be appreciated :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: If server send you the values then why are you generating your own to compare?

Comment: No I don't compare... I just have to take that speeds to randomize my game objects and nothing....But server sends the speed chunks that I assign to game objects and then the winners don't match from both the sides. :(

Comment: Then show some relevant code if you can

Comment: It can't be done there are more than 3 classes that m using :9

Comment: Send, receive and assigning code chunks

Comment: Yeah m doing it n that way only but is there any wrong that is happening from server side by which the objects don't match from both the sides?

Comment: What to do now...? :( Everyone is blaming me that m not doing my job well :,(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34532/discussion-between-hamza-hasan-and-shraddha-patel).

Comment: @HamzaHasan You guys should stick to English all across the site, even in chat rooms, specially those related to a question. If the problem is solved in chat and visitors can't read it, that's not good for them.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder how are you trying to sync it, the "best" way to do this is via socket connection.

Also, you have to identify the important info that you really need to sync, FE, im developing an MRTS, i have to sync the units but the client doesn´t care about movement speed, attack points, etc, so, in essence i only need send to the client which unit he has to draw, who owns this unit and where it has to be drawn, so, a huge object called "Archer" in my serverside application would be sent to the server as an Int8 array like [23,1,1851,2434] (Unit id, owner id, X, Y).

Then, your client only has to draw it.

If you use UDP sockets (fast as hell) and condensed bit data you will be able to do real time sync without any problem.

Comment: Not voting down your answer, but your answer is irrelevant. OP can't assign properly the value he/she fetch. Without code, it is difficult to point out

Comment: Thanks sir for the reply...me too just doing that way as u said.. just receive the command and by entry and key values the speeds automatically assign to that objects but then too the objects don't match from both the side. Am I doing anything wrong? or server?

Comment: Are you sure you are not making calcs in clientside? also, are your objects clearly identificables so, once a packet arrives, they could be updated?

Comment: That's why I asked for code :)

Comment: Hamza, you are right, there's no info enough, i just pointed out how it "should" be done, just in case OP didn't know how manage real time sync, i never said it's the final solution.

As Hamza said, you should post some more info OP, code, chart or flow would be appreciated